# Finding text between two delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, text, delimiter

I have a string **ABC_DEF_EFG_IJK**

I need to extract the text between two delimiters, but the condition is is **DEF_EFG** must be always together.

I have tried using split method, but it does not give right context.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your expected output? Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do. What is your desired result from the given string? What do you mean by `DEF_EFG` must be together? Literally the letters `DEF` and `EFG` or the middle group. Could there be more than three `_`? Try showing a couple strings and desired results.

Comment: Hi, the output will be **DEF_EFG**.

Comment: Sorry, English not my first language. The string is ABC_DEF_EFG_IJK, I need to extract from the string which the output will be DEF_EFG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for Python 3+:

```
letters = 'ABC_DEF_EFG_IJK'

splitted = letters.split('_')
final = f'{splitted[1]}_{splitted[2]}'

print(final)
```

And you should have:

```
DEF_EFG
```

If you use Python 2:

```
# replace this line
final = f'{splitted[1]}_{splitted[2]}'

#with this line
final = '{}_{}'.format(splitted[1], splitted[2])
```